# How to translate ‘anyway’?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a good translation for the word *anyway* with the meaning of getting back to a previously interrupted subject?

Say you're talking about something, then you go off on some tangent. Usually when getting back to the original subject from the tangent, you introduce this with *anyway*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Ĉiuokaze* ("in any case") eble uziĝas tiasence.

Answer (score 6):

You can use either "*ĉiuokaze*" or "*ĉiukaze*" for saying "*anyway*". The difference between them comes from the difference between the two words "*okazo*" and "*kazo*", which can both be used to translate the English word "*case*", even though they are not perfect synonyms in Esperanto. For details about the difference between "*okazo*" and "*kazo*", you can read my [article at Lingva Kritiko](http://lingvakritiko.com/2016/01/14/la-kazo-de-kazo/) about these words.

Answer (score 1):

Other than *ĉiuokaze*/*ĉiukaze*, I think *iel ajn* can be used too.

Comment: I am not sure whether that works in this particular context. Do you have a reference where it is used in this way? To me *iel ajn* seems to be a correct translation for ‘any way’ (with space!), which would mean “in any which way”.

Comment: Sorry, I have no reference. I just think it was worth adding since “ĉiuokaze”  is kind of a literal translation too (= “in all cases”), as in “in any which way, this doesn't matter, let's go back to the main subject” / “in all cases, this doesn't matter, let's go back to the main subject”.

Comment: I see! I actually find *iel ajn* a more obvious literal translation that doesn't quite fit as well as *ĉiu(o)kaze*! In Dutch we say “hoe dan ook” for ‘anyway’ in the sense described in the question, which precisely translates to *kiel ajn*. Hence it sounds a bit odd to me :p.